# Oracle APEX: IR to MSEXCEL Error

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

Here is a screenshot of the error occuring when I try to download the file using a button as described here:

[IR to MSEXCEL Manual](https://github.com/glebovpavel/IR_to_MSExcel/blob/master/Instructions.pdf)

[image: Error Page]

Can anybody show me a step-by-step way of solving this? I really want to learn troubleshooting in APEX.

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of XML_TO_XLSX.sqf at line 851:

[image: Screenshot of Code]

EDIT 2:
[Link to Github Issue](https://github.com/glebovpavel/IR_to_MSExcel/issues/22)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution myself, tt was an issue with execution rights.

Running

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON UTL_FILE TO PUBLIC
```

and recompiling all packages fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I also have this plug-in in my application (working fine).  According to the error message you show there is a problem at line 851 of body of package XML_TO_XSLX.  You can look at this package code to see what that line does. In my copy (which may be a different version to yours, I don't know) I see:

[image: Code of package]

That would suggest that Oracle could not find `dbms_lob.create_temporary` - which seems unlikely unless you are running in a very old version of Oracle. Have a look at your version of XML_TO_XSLX to see what is at line 851 there.

Another possibility is that line:

```
pragma inline(get_excel,'YES');
```

That is an feature of Oracle [added in 11G](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=502) that I have never used. It won't work on earlier versions - I have no idea what would happen if you tried.

Comment: please take a look at the new screenshot I provided. I just opened XML_TO_XLSX.sql and went to line 851, which definitly looks different from what your screenshot shows.

Comment: What is on line 1 of package?  Mine is `create or replace PACKAGE BODY  "XML_TO_XSLX" `.

Comment: Yep, it's ' CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE  XML_TO_XSLX ', but without the quotes.

Comment: OK, then I'm as baffled as you are, sorry!

Comment: Damn it! But thank you, that disproves me being incapable at least.

Comment: I found something: The line "SET DEFINE OFF" in the install_all_packages.sql is being ignored when I run it. Normal or maybe cause of the problem?

Comment: I don't think it is relevant.  It would just mean that the text '&quot'` that appears in the code would cause a prompt for input and get replaced by whatever was entered.  So functionality would be impacted but not result in that runtime error.